# Plot graphs in R by loop and save it like jpeg

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I am trying to plot graphs by loop.

Input data: Tables, which have the same ending *depth.txt, there are 2 tab delimited columns in the table:

```
Baba"\t"58.38

Tata"\t"68.38

Mama"\t"30.80

jaja"\t"88.65
```

OUTPUT: I would like to get a jpeg file with `plot()` for each *depth.txt (their names will be the same as the tables' names) for all files (axis x will be the first column from the table and axis y will be second column)

I created a part of the script, but it doesn't work:

```
files <- list.files(path="/home/fil/Desktop/", pattern="*depth.txt", full.names=T,recursive=FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(files))
plot(read.table(files[i],header=F,sep="\t")$V1,read.table(files[i],header=F,sep="\t")$V2)
dev.copy(jpeg,filename=files[i])
dev.off
```

It doesn't work, could you help me please? I am a beginner with R.

Comment: Try including the loop-body in `{ ... }`.

Comment: I tried it, it is good idea, but still time I am receiving only one .jpeg, with two graphs (first one is Ok, but second is with wrong values) and the name of jpeg is wrong too :-(

Comment: Strange - I have tried something like this as well some time ago and it didn't work either. Looking forward to the solution. Back then, I just used `par(mfrow=c(3,4))` (which if put before the loop, will plot all the graphs on one page, 3 horizontally and 4 vertically) and then saved the whole plot in the end...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will the following do what you want?

```
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  dat <- read.table(files[i], header = FALSE, sep = '\t')
  jpeg(file = paste(files[i], '.jpeg', sep = ''))
  plot(dat$V1, dat$V2)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works but it rewrite my .txt file, but it is my fault with explanation of output. Is it possible to create graph without overwrite? Thank you for the working script. I saw I was close, but how I said I am beginner in R :-( Thank you so much..

Comment: Dear Lars, thank you for this great help. It is works only missing one ) , but it is not mistake. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the first two but changing the file name for the plots

```
files <- paste("fil",1:3,"depth.txt",sep="")      #  example file names
for( i in 1:length(files))  {
     filename <-  sub(".txt",".jpg",files[i])
     jpeg(file=filename)
     plot(1:(10*i))                             # example plots
     dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

renameing the file?

```
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    file = files[i]
    file = paste("jpg",file,sep="_")
    jpeg(file)
    plot(read.table(files[i],header=F,sep="\t")$V1,read.table(files[i],header=F,sep="\t")$V2)
   dev.off()
}
```