# A for loop for multiple likert graphs returns NOTHING

Tags: r, likert

I set up a large amount of likert and other graphs to evaluate the total results of my questionnaire.

Now I would like to do the same thing by a grouping variable "group"

I set up all of my likert items and their definitions (my data is in a god-awful format, so I had to reformat it with R). The idea for the code is the following:
1. group and rename the questions according to the likert () functions needs
2. have R split the dataframe according to 11 groups
3. plot a likert graph for each of these groups

Now this should be the solution (it worked for the barplots but for some reason is not working for the likert plots):

```
for(i in 1:11)
{
x<-F5[which(F5$group==i),]
plot(likert(x[1:9]),low.color="red3", high.color="forestgreen",
 include.center=T, plot.percents=T,ordered=T, 
 legend= paste("F5","Gruppe",i), 
 legend.position="bottom",
 plot.percent.low=F,plot.percent.high=F)+ylab(ylab)+ggtitle(title.F5)
}
```

when I run this code exactly NOTHING happens. No likert graphs are plotted, no error messages etc.

EXAMPLE DATA so everyone can join the fun:

```
 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 group
1   1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     1
2   2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     1
3   3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     1
4   1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     1
5   2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     2
6   1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     2
7   2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     2
8   3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     3
9   4  5  5  1  2  4 -9  1  3     3
10  5  5 -9  1  3  4  4  2 -9     3
11  3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     3
12  4  5  5  1  2  4 -9  1  3     4
13  5  5 -9  1  3  4  4  2 -9     3
14  5  5 -9  1  3  4  4  2 -9     3
15  3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     4
16  1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     4
17  2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     4
18  1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     4
19  2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     4
20  3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     4
```

1. Change data from numeric to likert-style items of agreement

   ```
   DATA[,1:9][DATA[,1:9]==1]<-"strongly agree"
   DATA[,1:9][DATA[,1:9]==2]<-"agree"
   DATA[,1:9][DATA[,1:9]==3]<-"unsure"
   DATA[,1:9][DATA[,1:9]==4]<-"disagree"
   DATA[,1:9][DATA[,1:9]==5]<-"strongly disagree"
   DATA[,1:9][DATA[,1:9]==-9]<-NA
   ```
2. Set agreement scale

   ```
   agr<-c("stronlgy agree", "agree", "unsure", "disagree", "strongly disagree")
   ```
3. Define each as ordered factors to the previously defined scale

   ```
   DATA[,1]=factor(DATA[,1], levels=agr, ordered=TRUE)
   DATA[,2]=factor(DATA[,2], levels=agr, ordered=TRUE)
   DATA[,3]=factor(DATA[,3], levels=agr, ordered=TRUE)
   DATA[,4]=factor(DATA[,4], levels=agr, ordered=TRUE)
   DATA[,5]=factor(DATA[,5], levels=agr, ordered=TRUE)
   DATA[,6]=factor(DATA[,6], levels=agr, ordered=TRUE)
   DATA[,7]=factor(DATA[,7], levels=agr, ordered=TRUE)
   DATA[,8]=factor(DATA[,8], levels=agr, ordered=TRUE)
   DATA[,9]=factor(DATA[,9], levels=agr, ordered=TRUE)
   ```
4. set title to sth funny

   title.DATA<-"This message will not show up because R is stupid."
5. program a loop and watch R do NOTHING

   for(i in 1:11)
   {
   x<-DATA[which(DATA$group==i),]
   plot(likert(x[1:9]),low.color="red3", high.color="forestgreen",
   include.center=T, plot.percents=T,ordered=T, 
   legend= paste("DATA","Gruppe",i), 
   legend.position="bottom",
   plot.percent.low=F,plot.percent.high=F)+ylab(ylab)+ggtitle(title.DATA)
   }

Comment: Your `for()` loop won't return anything unless you explicitly ask it to return something. In this case it might be appropriate to save the plot with `dev.new()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32051089/3022126

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot graphs in R by loop and save it like jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048305/plot-graphs-in-r-by-loop-and-save-it-like-jpeg)

Comment: you should pre-define `data` before the for loop in your code, I'm guessing a list would be appropriate.

Comment: @Phil comment 1: If this were the case, then why does the same loop work like a charm for a barplot?

Comment: @Phil comment 2: I don't kjnow how to convince you that this question is not a duplicate. I do not need to export my plot as a jpeg. So if it works for barplot () and not for likert () this clearly isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide some minimal data to get your plot working? For help see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Without being able to reproduce your problem I don't know why `barplot` works but this doesn't.

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen: The likert graph parameters are generate by the likert() function from the likert package, other than that, base R

Comment: @Phil: I edited the example and added my data processing steps as well as a reduced version of the loop I had in mind...

Comment: @RomainB.: I don't understand what you mean? pre-define data?

Comment: @Gmichael In the first version of your post, it looked like the first instance of `data` in you code was during the for loop. You've since changed it so don't mind my comment, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me like that. I came across this problem myself recently. graphics plots print automatically in loops, grid plots don't. For them you have to add `print`.

```
library(likert)

for(i in 1:4) { x<-DATA[which(DATA$group==i),] 
lp <- plot(likert(x[1:9]),low.color="red3", 
high.color="forestgreen", include.center=T, 
plot.percents=T,ordered=T, legend= paste("DATA","Gruppe", i), 
legend.position="bottom", plot.percent.low=F,plot.percent.high=F) +
  ylab("ylab") +
  ggtitle("This message will not show up because R is stupid.")

print(lp)
}
```

Comment: I am implementing this version in my 56 likert questions and some return an error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'pos' not found... any ideas?

Comment: and this one: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, group

Comment: yes, I had the first one, too, when `i` stood for a group that was not in the data. But I wonder abotu the second one. Do they occur together?

Comment: No, they occur separately and it seems like some of the more specific questions (i.e. filter questions people were only asked if they had answered a previous question in a specific way) have this problem... How do I get around that apart from using for( i in c(1:3,5)) if there is no group 4?

Comment: You can do `for( i in unique(DATA$group)) ` for example.

Comment: Shame.. Unfortunately I don't know your data well enough to be able to guess where the error might come from. If you don't find out which variables cause the problem you could open a new question?

Comment: I might have to do that... interestingly enough it works for every plot individually. And, funny observation: I accidentally left " legend=paste( "Frage 11 Gruppe",i)" in the code and executed it for "x<-F11[which(F11$group==1),]" and it pastes 2 for i

Comment: SOLUTION: likert refuses to produce a item of class "likert" if the amount of samples is <=1, so with the more specific questions and smaller groups that is very possible. Now I know what my next question will be

Comment: Cool, hau rein. ;-)