# for loop for unique values with more than 1 occurrence

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a questionnaire (yes it is the same one from all my questions so far...[A for loop for multiple likert graphs returns NOTHING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650737/a-for-loop-for-multiple-likert-graphs-returns-nothing))

Now I am evaluating the answers per geographical region (11 regions), which I want to do with a for loop.

The liker package used to make my graphs won't plot any graph for <=1 non-NA answers. So neither of these work properly:

My (hypothetical) data looks something like this (-9 denotes NA):

```
 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 group
1   1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     1
2   2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     1
3   3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     1
4   1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     1
5   2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     2
6   1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     2
7   2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     2
8   3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     3
9   4  5  5  1  2  4 -9  1  3     3
10  5  5 -9  1  3  4  4  2 -9     3
11  3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     3
12  4  5  5  1  2  4 -9  1  3     4
13  5  5 -9  1  3  4  4  2 -9     3
14  5  5 -9  1  3  4  4  2 -9     3
15  3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     4
16  1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     4
17  2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     4
18  1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     4
19  2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     4
20  3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     4
21  -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9    5
22  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1     6
```

These two version of for-looping will not work:

```
for (i in 1:5)
for (i in unique(mydata$group))
```

because: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'pos' not found

Which I think is because  group 5 contains only N/As and group 6 contains only one sample.

So I need a function executable via my for loop which only creates values for i that have more than 2 rows which are non-N/A. Any ideas?

Comment: What is 'pos' ? What does that objects do in your code ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @CuriousBeing: I do not have an object "pos" in my entire code... even searched for it....

Comment: are you just missing a ")" at the end of "for (i in unique(mydata$group)"

Comment: @RonakShah: A likert plot (function likert() from pkg likert) for each group individually

Comment: @MatthewR: Nope, but thx for the watchful eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask inside your loop if the condition is given that there are more than 2 rows which are non-N/A.

```
mydata <- read.table(text = "
 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 group
1   1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     1
2   2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     1
3   3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     1
4   1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     1
5   2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     2
6   1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     2
7   2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     2
8   3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     3
9   4  5  5  1  2  4 -9  1  3     3
10  5  5 -9  1  3  4  4  2 -9     3
11  3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     3
12  4  5  5  1  2  4 -9  1  3     4
13  5  5 -9  1  3  4  4  2 -9     3
14  5  5 -9  1  3  4  4  2 -9     3
15  3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     4
16  1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     4
17  2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     4
18  1  5  5  1  2  4  4 -9  5     4
19  2  4  5  1  2  4  4  1  5     4
20  3  3  5  1  2  4  3  1  3     4
21  -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9    5
22  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1     6
", header=T, na.strings="-9")

for (i in unique(mydata$group)) {
  x <- mydata[mydata$group==i,]
  if(sum(complete.cases(x)) > 2) { #more than 2 rows which are non-N/A?
    plot(x[1:9])
  }
}
```