# Saving all of the graphs from a for loop to one figure file

Tags: r

I want to plot 12 graphs into one figure.
Right now I wrote this code:

```
everyEleven <- split(Theoph,ceiling(seq(nrow(Theoph))/11))
everyEleven

# SUbject numbers
pos_vec = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

# One plot
plot(everyEleven[[12]]$Time, everyEleven[[12]]$conc, type = "l", main = "Subject 1")


# Several plots

plot_list = list()

par(mfrow=c(2,6))
plot_list

for (i in length(everyEleven)) {
  plot(everyEleven[[i]]$Time, everyEleven[[i]]$conc, type = "l", main = paste("Subject",pos_vec[i]), xlab= "Time", ylab= "Concenctration")
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}
```

It gets me the plots but only saves the last one (the 12th one) and then doesn't save the rest. I know how to save to jpeg file all the plots 1 by 1, but I am struggling with saving all of the 12 plots in one figure. Could someone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot graphs in R by loop and save it like jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048305/plot-graphs-in-r-by-loop-and-save-it-like-jpeg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple error, You do not loop over all plots but just over the last one. Add `1:length()`

```
for (i in 1:length(everyEleven)) { # added 1:
  plot(everyEleven[[i]]$Time, everyEleven[[i]]$conc, type = "l", main = paste("Subject",pos_vec[i]), xlab= "Time", ylab= "Concenctration")
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}
```

Comment: OMG yes! I added the 1: and it worked instantly. THANK YOU SO MUCH!